# How do list command on one ssh command?

Tags: unix, ssh

I try connect with ssh2 and run script in one line command.

> /usr/bin/ssh2 --password ${password} -l root ${address} cd ${dir} ;
>   python script.py

But directory isn't changed. Why ? I want write with two command.
It does only first command (cd)

Comment: Try putting quotes around what you want to run

Comment: Don't work @JoeyHarwood

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should use && instead of ; and put command in " 
example:
/usr/bin/ssh2 --password ${password} -l root ${address} "cd ${dir} && python script.py"

Comment: I tested it and it was working for me, however try to manually type the password and try to do it with some other command, instead of the python script test it with something else.